# How to perform a "NOT IN" from an array in another array in aggregate (MongoDB)

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregate, notin

I am trying to perform a "NOT IN" from an array to another array, but I can't find a simple answer for my case.

At some step of my aggregate I get this set of results:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5c2e433599c7f42096546118"),
  stuffToExclude: [
    ObjectId("b00000000000000000010001",
    ObjectId("b00000000000000000010002",
  ],
  stuffGetFrom: [
    ObjectId("b00000000000000000010001",
    ObjectId("b00000000000000000010002",
    ObjectId("b00000000000000000010003",
    ObjectId("b00000000000000000010004",
    ObjectId("b00000000000000000010005",
  ],
}
```

And I need to do something that gets me this result:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5c2e433599c7f42096546118"),
  stuffIWant: [
    ObjectId("b00000000000000000010003",
    ObjectId("b00000000000000000010004",
    ObjectId("b00000000000000000010005",
  ],
}
```

Could someone please tell me how to do this simple magic trick ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Use `db.collectionname.aggregate(
   [
     { $project: { stuffIWant: { $setDifference: [ "$stuffGetFrom", "$stuffToExclude" ] } } }
   ]
)`